# Understanding TTL values in DNS query answers using dig

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup, dig

I'm querying `google.com` with `dig` and I'm having a hard time understanding why TTL values sometimes *jump around* instead of decrementing every second uniformly (which is my expectation). What am I missing here?

Here's what I'm doing on my Windows machine with `dig` installed (DiG 9.16.7, from the BIND 9 distribution).

```
c:\>for /l %i in (1,1,10) do @(sleep 1 & dig @1.1.1.1 +noall +answer google.com)
google.com.             163     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             168     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             166     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             166     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             157     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             160     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             163     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             160     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             163     IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             156     IN      A       172.217.19.110
```

The first response has a TTL of 163, the second is 168, etc. ... my expectation was that TTL decrements until it reaches zero.

Then I've searched around and it seems `dig` doesn't use the hosts (OS-level or other) DNS cache (like a browser would), which explains why the number is not decrementing, however, it doesn't answer why it's all over the place.

If I don't specify 1.1.1.1 as the nameserver and instead rely on my IPS it's even weirder.

```
c:\>for /l %i in (1,1,10) do @(sleep 1 & dig +noall +answer google.com)
google.com.             56      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             55      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             54      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             52      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             50      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             47      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             48      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             45      IN      A       172.217.18.78
google.com.             6       IN      A       172.217.19.110
google.com.             64      IN      A       172.217.19.110
```

I've also tried `nslookup -debug google.com` but I experience the same with regards to TTL values as with `dig`.

What am I missing here? Thanks for the input.

Comment: What server are you querying in the second case?

Comment: My ISPs DNS server at 213.46.246.53.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple boxes behind `1.1.1.1` or any other similar public DNS resolver. Hence, technically, all those boxes can share their DNS cache, or not.

If they don't, each one will have different set of records cached, and different TTLs associated to them.

What you observe may seem puzzling but has 0 negative effects on the DNS service.

Comment: And FWIW, Google Public DNS instances do not share cache among themselves.